# How can I forward scrolling the RecyclerView to its parent which is a BottomSheet in order to collapse it?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager, bottom-sheet

Basically I have a fragment with a specific layout, which has CoordinatorLayout as its parent and a static fragment with BottomSheetBehaviour(also some other views that are not related to the question) 
`

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_activity_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

       Some other views....

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/home_apps_widget"
            android:name="apps.calo.justLauncher.fragments.HomeAppsWidget"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="57dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet_container"
        android:name="apps.calo.justLauncher.fragments.AppDrawerFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout="@layout/app_drawer_fragament"
        app:behavior_hideable="true"
        app:behavior_peekHeight="0dp"
        app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior"
        tools:layout="@layout/app_drawer_fragament" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

`

Inside the static fragment, I have the following layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/app_drawer_root"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/app_drawer_background">

        <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
            android:id="@+id/view_pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@id/app_drawer_indicator"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:layout_below="@id/app_search_widget"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/app_list_recycler"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:itemCount="4"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            app:spanCount="4"
            tools:listitem="@layout/app_item"
            android:layout_above="@id/app_drawer_indicator"
            app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_below="@id/app_search_widget"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />

        <apps.calo.justLauncher.view.Pager2Indicator
            android:id="@+id/app_drawer_indicator"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="11dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            app:piv_radius="3dp"
            app:selectedColorCustom="page_indicator_selected"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="3dp"
            app:unselectedColorCustom="page_indicator_unselected" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</layout>
```

With the following setup, you can only have one active (recyclerview or viewpager2), which can be altered with SharedPreferences.

My goal is, when you scroll the RecyclerView to the top, your next scroll would be taken over by the bottom sheet(if you try to scroll recyclerview to the top again) and the touch would move the Y position of the bottom sheet.

I want the same thing with the viewpager but here you don't have to scroll to the top because it is not scrollable, so basically if you scroll towards down, the bottom sheet would take over the touch.

With the current setup both RecyclerView and ViewPager "swallow" the touch and you are not able to control the bottom sheet from them. You can still colapse the bottom sheet if you pull it down by touching on the view that is above recyclerview/viewpager.

**My question is: How can I delegate the touch from the recyclerview/viewpager to the BottomSheet in order to control Y position of BottomSheet.**

The interesting thing is, when I change the ViewPager2 to ViewPager, I have the desired effect with the RecyclerView, but not with ViewPager.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I figured a way to do this. I attached a touch listener to RecyclerView and ViewPager. Created an interface that connects two fragments(fragment that contains the bottom sheet and the bottom sheet fragment). In the case of RecyclerView being visible, I would check if the RecyclerView is scrolled to the top. If it is, I would check if the user is swiping towards down with the touch listener. If he is, I forward the touch to Fragment which contains the BottomSheet and forward the touch event with the root view of BottomSheet, and run this method:

```
fun forwardTouchToBottomSheet(event: MotionEvent, view: View) {
        bottomSheetBehavior.onTouchEvent(cor, view, event)
    }
```

In the case of ViewPager, the touch listener would not work on ViewPager2 view(because views would take over the touch I guess) so I just put the listener on views inside the ViewPager and run the previous method through another interface.

Comment: Can you please provide more code? Have the same problem!

Comment: I get the following error "captureChildView: parameter must be a descendant of the ViewDragHelper's tracked parent view " When doing as you described. Not sure what to pass att `cor` in your example. Tried sending both `coordinatorLayout` and the `coordinatorLayout` of the parent bottom dialog fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't answer directly to @Sunkas follow-up question because of low rep, I'll expand on answer here.

If I initialized behavior inside BottomSheetDialogFragment as this:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreaBottted(view, savedInstanceState)
    val behaviour = BottomSheetBehavior.from(view.parent as View).apply {
        state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED
    }
}
```

Then calling onTouchEvent required view.parent.parent and view.parent, like this:

```
        binding.recyclerView.apply {
        setOnTouchListener { _, event ->
            (requireView().parent.parent as? CoordinatorLayout)?.let { coordinatorLayout ->
                (requireView().parent as? View)?.let { parentView ->
                    behaviour.onTouchEvent(coordinatorLayout, parentView, event)
                }
            } ?: false
        }
```